# DynamoDB Query expression on partitionKey

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamodb-mapper

i have one AmazonDynamoDB whose hashKey is: "userId" and rangeKey is: "timestamp".

```
I am writing one query for fetching up all records related to particular userId.

String keyConditionExpression = "userId = :userId";
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attributeValuesMap = new HashMap<>();
attributeValuesMap.put(":userId", new AttributeValue().withS("someId"));

DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyTableItem> queryExpression =
                new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyTableItem>()
                .withKeyConditionExpression(keyConditionExpression)
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributeValuesMap)
                .withConsistentRead(false);

dynamoDBMapper.queryPage(MyTableItem.class, queryExpression);
```

this query operation is failing, but not able to see, why it's failing.
[As given here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#:%7E:text=aws%20dynamodb%20query%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%2D%2Dtable%2Dname%20Thread%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%2D%2Dkey%2Dcondition%2Dexpression%20%22ForumName%20%3D%20%3Aname%22%20%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%2D%2Dexpression%2Dattribute%2Dvalues%20%20%27%7B%22%3Aname%22%3A%7B%22S%22%3A%22Amazon%20DynamoDB%22%7D%7D%27), this should come under query criteria.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code and it runs as expected, returning the correct results. Is `userId` your tables Partition Key?

Can you share which error you are getting, that will help to recommend a solution.

```
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

    String keyConditionExpression = "userId = :userId";
    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attributeValuesMap = new HashMap<>();
    attributeValuesMap.put(":userId", new AttributeValue().withS("leeroy"));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<BillingDashboardRecord> queryExpression =
            new DynamoDBQueryExpression<BillingDashboardRecord>()
                    .withKeyConditionExpression(keyConditionExpression)
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(attributeValuesMap)
                    .withConsistentRead(false);

    try{
        mapper.queryPage(BillingDashboardRecord.class, queryExpression);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```